# Why is the Calendar before() method returning true for equal dates

Tags: java, date, calendar

I am setting a color field based on how the `dueDate` field compares to the current date.  `dueDate` is an SQL Date type.  My problem is when I pass in the current date the `Calendar.before()` method says the date is before the current date.  My code is:

```
private String getDateDueColor(Date dateDue) {
      Calendar today =  Calendar.getInstance();
      today.setTime(new java.sql.Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime()));
      Calendar dueDate = Calendar.getInstance();
      dueDate.setTime(dateDue);
      if(dueDate.before(today)){
        return RED;
      }else{
        return NORMAL;
      }
  }
```

I have set a breakpoint and compared `dueDate` and `today` and all of the information in the `cdate` field for each object looks identical, but the `dueDate.before(today)` still returns true.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What's the value of dateDue

Comment: `Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime()` is an unnecessarily verbose and cryptic way of doing `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Comment: I found Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime() on a StackOverflow post.  Thanks for the shorter version.

Comment: dateDue was 2016/2/19 the day I tested it.

Comment: use if(dueDate.getTimeInMillis() < today.getTimeInMillis) instead of if(dueDate.before(today)
Hope this help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure they are equal? Method `equals` for `Date` and `Calendar` means they represents the same time value (millisecond offset from the Epoch). See the [javadocs for `Calendar.equals` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

> Compares this Calendar to the specified Object. The result is true if and only if the argument is a Calendar object of the same calendar system that represents **the same time value (millisecond offset from the Epoch) under the same Calendar parameters as this object**.

The [`before` method docs states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#before-java.lang.Object-) that `compareTo` is used to decide if a calendar instance is before another. And again, `compareTo` is using millisecond precision. From [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#compareTo-java.util.Calendar-):

> Compares the **time values (millisecond offsets from the Epoch)** represented by two Calendar objects.

The alternatives are:

1. If you have to use Calendar, create new instances, use `clear` method on them and then set values (year, month, hourOfDay, minute, second) using the [`set` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set-int-int-int-int-int-).
2. Use the new [java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) and choose some type that better represents what you want (maybe [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html))
3. Use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) if you can't go to Java 8.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: For my purposes I only need the day, month and year set.  After I clear the Calendar instance, how do I know what to set the fields to.  Do I use the get method with an uncleared Calendar instance?

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by marcospereira](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35511131/642706) is correct. I'll add some general suggestions about revamping the code shown in the Question, and show the use of java.time.

## Use java.sql only for database transfer

Do not pass around java.sql types and perform business logic on them. Use java.sql only for transferring data in and out of the database. For java.sql.Timestamp/[.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html)/.Time immediately convert them to java.time objects. Then proceed with your business logic.

```
LocalDate due = myJavaSqlDate.toLocalDate();
```

## Avoid old date-time classes

Avoid the old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java such as java.util.Date/.Calendar. They are confusing, poorly designed, and troublesome.

## java.time

In Java 8 and later, the old date-time class have been supplanted by the java.time framework. These new classes are a *vast* improvement. Inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), defined by JSR 310, and extended by the ThreeTen-Extra project.

## Date-only Value

The code in the Question suggests that you want to work with date-only values such as [java.sql.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) pretends to be. Yet you mix it with [java.util.Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) which represents a date *and* a time-of-day.

Above in this Answer you can the [`java.time.LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class. This class represents a date-only value without time-of-day nor time zone.

## Time Zone

Time zone is crucial when dealing with date-only values. A date-only (without time-of-day) is inherently ambiguous. The date is not the same around the world at any given moment. A new day dawns earlier in the east. Minutes after midnight in Paris is still “yesterday” in Montréal.

So to determine “today” requires a time zone. If not specified, your JVM’s current default time zone is implicitly applied. Not good. Results may vary at runtime depending on settings of the host operating system and of the JVM. The default time zone can even be changed during runtime by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

So, better to specify the desired/expected time zone explicitly.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zoneId );
```

Now compare to see if the due date has passed.

```
if( today.isAfter( due ) ) {
    // Overdue.
}
```

Comment: You are correct I only need the date-only information but I also need to change the date by 15 days in another part of the code which is why I used the Calendar class.    Our project uses Java 7 so I can't use the new framework.  I could ask and see if we could include Joda-Time.  This code is never going to be used across time zones so do I still need to worry about explicitly declaring the time zone?

Comment: To change a date, call the `plusDays` or `minusDays` method: `today.plusDays( 15 )`. As for specifying the time zone, yes always specify explicitly. If a sysadmin changes the time zone on the host OS, or specifies a switch on the command-line launching the JVM, your software goes haywire with wrong dates. That is a *horrible* problem to try to debug. If you expect time zone `America/LosAngeles` or `Europe/Paris` or `Asia/Kolkata`, then say so. Make a constant and use it all over. As for Joda-Time, yes definitely use it if before Java 8; has equivalent `LocalDate` and time zone classes.

Comment: @ponder275 **Update:** The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. The project recommends migration to the java.time classes. For Java 6 & 7, use the *ThreeTen-Backport* project instead of Joda-Time. For earlier Android, see the *ThreeTenABP* project.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to compare yyyy, mm, dd fields. If they are the same - dont use .after() nor .before()
Simon Franz